# how to save data from textview when going to previous activity kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity, sharedpreferences, parent-child

So I have a child activity that I press two buttons, one to increment and one to decrement. I want to save this number when I go back to the previous activity. However, I am stuck here. I tried using shared preference, however that seems to work for main to secondary activity. I tried using Activity Result and that seems way above me right now. I want my value in the textView to stay until I press a button to reset the whole thing.

This is the parent activity.

```
import android.app.Activity
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity

class TallBoys : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tall_boys)


    val btn1: Button = findViewById(R.id.button1)
    val btn2: Button = findViewById(R.id.button2)
    val btn3: Button = findViewById(R.id.button3)
    val btn4: Button = findViewById(R.id.button4)
    val btn5: Button = findViewById(R.id.button5)
    val btn6: Button = findViewById(R.id.button6)
    val btn7: Button = findViewById(R.id.button7)



    btn1.setOnClickListener {
        val intent = Intent(this, TallBoysNumbers::class.java)

    }

    btn2.setOnClickListener {
        val intent = Intent(this, TallBoysNumbers::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }

    btn3.setOnClickListener {
        val intent = Intent(this, TallBoysNumbers::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
    btn4.setOnClickListener {
        val intent = Intent(this, TallBoysNumbers::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
    btn5.setOnClickListener {
        val intent = Intent(this, TallBoysNumbers::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
    btn6.setOnClickListener {
        val intent = Intent(this, TallBoysNumbers::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
    btn7.setOnClickListener {
        val intent = Intent(this, TallBoysNumbers::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }


}
```

}

This is the child activity

```
import android.app.Activity
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity


class TallBoysNumbers : AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tall_boys_numbers)





    val confirmBtn: Button = findViewById(R.id.confirm_button)
    val plusBtn: Button = findViewById(R.id.plus)
    val textView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.numbers)
    val negBtn: Button = findViewById(R.id.negative)
    var count = 0



    plusBtn.setOnClickListener {
        count++
        textView.text = count.toString()
        if (count >= 8) {
            plusBtn.isEnabled = false
            negBtn.isEnabled = true
        }

    }


    negBtn.setOnClickListener {
        count--
        textView.text = count.toString()
        if (count <= 0) {
            negBtn.isEnabled = false
            plusBtn.isEnabled = true
        }
    }




        confirmBtn.setOnClickListener {
            finish()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: SharedPreferences should work fine, show what you tried. Granted, based on what you showed `startActivityForResult` would probably be more appropriate.

Comment: Well I tried to use startActivityForResult and this seems to be the best method. I am close however think I am having difficulty with the textView part of the code. Everytime I press the confirm button, it skips the parent activity and goes all the way back to the main menu.

Comment: It's not really clear what you want to happen here. After setting a number in the child activity you want that displayed in the parent activity? And persisted so the number reloads if they launch the app again?

Comment: Yes to both. I also want to display that number right next to the button in the parent activity that it is correlated to.

Comment: I am actually thinking of changing the second activity to a fragment.

Comment: There are nearly unlimited ways of doing this... You could use a ViewModel, just save and load from shared preferences, etc... You should try to make your question less open-ended...

Comment: Okay, how do I load the text view shared preferences value? I am able to save the value in the child class. But then when I go back to parent and then back to child, the textview says 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to do this, so I'm just going to show how to do it using `SharedPreferences`. The steps you need are:

1. In the parent activity, load the saved numbers from SharedPreferences in `onResume` and set the views accordingly. This needs to be in `onResume` so that it is also called when returning from the child activity after the numbers are modified.
2. Pass the key that is being edited to the child activity, so that it can save it in the correct spot in the SharedPreferences. The child activity can also use this key to load the current value so it is initialized correctly.

For example, in the parent activity

```kotlin
class ShowNumbersActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var prefs: SharedPreferences
    private lateinit var txt1: TextView
    private lateinit var txt2: TextView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_numbers)

        prefs = getSharedPreferences("MY_PREFS", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        
        val btn1 = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btn1)
        val btn2 = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btn2)

        txt1 = findViewById(R.id.txt1)
        txt2 = findViewById(R.id.txt2)

        // When you click on "Button 1" you have to signal
        // to the second activity which key you are editing
        btn1.setOnClickListener {
            val i = Intent(this, PickNumber::class.java)
            i.putExtra("KEY","VAL1")
            startActivity(i)
        }

        btn2.setOnClickListener {
            val i = Intent(this, PickNumber::class.java)
            i.putExtra("KEY","VAL2")
            startActivity(i)
        }
    }

    // Update the displayed state in onResume
    // so that it is updated after returning from the
    // child activity editing the number
    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()

        val num1 = prefs.getInt("VAL1", 0)
        val num2 = prefs.getInt("VAL2", 0)

        txt1.text = num1.toString()
        txt2.text = num2.toString()
    }
}
```

Then in the child activity, get the "KEY" and the same SharedPreferences instance and edit it when you click "Submit"

```kotlin
class PickNumber : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pick_number)

        val key = intent.getStringExtra("KEY")

        if( key == null ) {
            finish()
        }

        val prefs = getSharedPreferences("MY_PREFS", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        val txt = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.num)
        val submit = findViewById<Button>(R.id.submit)

        // load the current value and display it
        val current = prefs.getInt(key, 0)

        txt.setText(current.toString())

        submit.setOnClickListener {
            // Get the updated number, save it to shared preferences
            // (remember to call "apply") and finish this activity.
            // When onResume is called in the parent activity it will
            // load this updated number.
            val num = txt.text.toString()
            val numI = num.toIntOrNull() ?: 0
            prefs.edit().putInt(key, numI).apply()
            finish()
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to clear the numbers, you could make a button that calls `prefs.edit().clear().apply()` to erase all the saved values, or `prefs.edit().remove(someKey).apply()` to erase just one specific value.

There are definitely better ways to do this - if you switch to using a Fragment like you indicated these could be stored in a shared ViewModel that handles persistence and would be a cleaner design overall.

Comment: oh okay i think i get it more, so like my problem now is that I don't have individual textView for like txt1 and txt2. I would either have to create an individual activity for each textView or have txt1 and txt2 on the same page. I guess I wanted to create more of a loop so that for each button, I can add or subtract numbers. I guess fragment would be better for this? Thank you so much though, you helped me understand better.

Comment: is there a way to show you my xml file so that I can show you better what I am trying to achieve? I can't fit all the code in this comment section.

Comment: You need to write a more focused, specific question. This is not a code-writing service and this is too open-ended as-is.

Comment: thank you so much, I figured it out with your comments and help

Answer (score 0):

You are calling "finish" method. This will finish TallBoysNumbers activity without saving any data. Do not use SharedPreferences for that. What you'll need is "startActivityForResult".

This will allow you to save the data before calling "finish" AND getting it from the caller activity. Take a look here:

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result